# mac how to save alias in computer

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, alias

I created an alias on terminal, such as

```
alias hw="cd Desktop/2015hw"
```

but after I closed the terminal and do hw, there is an error message said there is no hw command.

I was wondering if we can save the alias on the computer.
Also, if we have stored the alias on the computer, how would we check it? By check it, I mean like list all alias we have stored.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the command to your `.bashrc` file

```
echo "alias hw='cd Desktop/2015hw'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Keep in mind that your alias will only work when you are in your home (as you are using a relative path)

```
echo "alias hw='cd ~/Desktop/2015hw'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Execute the saved alias by *sourcing* the file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: What do you mean by check? With `type hw` you get the configured alias for `hw`

Comment: by check, I meant that if there is a function like ls -alias or something like that, it will list all alias on the current computer, sorry for the confusion

Comment: to list the aliases `alias`

Answer (score 11):

When making an alias with `alias`, the alias is only valid until you close the terminal window. If you open another terminal window, the alias will no longer be present.

You can make an alias be valid for all terminal windows by placing it in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files (bash is the name of the terminal which Mac OS X ships with by default.)

Since Mac OS X does not load .bashrc by default, I would actually do:

```
echo "alias hw='cd ~/Desktop/2015hw'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

When you want to delete the alias, you can open your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files and delete it manually.

To open them, do `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` or `open -a TextEdit ~/.bashrc`

Finally, to list all your current aliases, simply type `alias` in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

your can start with type

```
ls -la
```

and then if you use bash typing

```
nano .bash_profile
```

or if you use zsh typing

```
nano .zshrc
```

then make alias save with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
for activating 
use 
`source ~/.bash_profile` or

```
source ~/.zsh
```